# How can I validate if a transaction number is sequential, if number restart for each date?

Tags: python, pandas

I already tried ChatGPT but the code it gave me does not render the expected results.

I have a database with "TransactionDate" and "TransactionNumber". I need to build a validation in Python that verifies if the "TransactionNumber" is sequential, and if not, export those records to an Excel table. However, the "TransactionNumber" restart from 1 for each "TransactionDate".

```
Example:
TransactionDate    TransactionNumber
08/11/2023         1
08/11/2023         2
08/11/2023         3
08/12/2023         1
08/12/2023         2
08/12/2023         3
08/13/2023         1
08/13/2023         3 (I need to catch this situation)
08/13/2023         3 (I need to catch this situation)
```

I tried the code below from ChatGPT but it does not identify the non sequential records. It return all the records, sequential or not sequential.

The code should return only the records that are non sequential.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data from Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel("BDPO_database.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Convert date to datetime
df['TransactionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TransactionNumber'])

# Create a function to check for non-sequential event numbers
def check_non_sequential(series):
    return ~series.diff().eq(1).all()

# Group by date and apply the function to check for non-sequential event numbers within each group
non_sequential_records = df.groupby('TransactionDate')['TransactionNumber'].apply(check_non_sequential)

# Get the dates with non-sequential event numbers
non_sequential_dates = non_sequential_records[non_sequential_records].index

# Filter out non-sequential records and export to an Excel file
non_sequential_df = df[df['TransactionDate'].isin(non_sequential_dates)]
non_sequential_df.to_excel('non_sequential_records.xlsx', index=False)
print("Registros não sequenciais exportados para 'non_sequential_records.xlsx'.")
```

Comment: We've gone from helping people to debugging chatgpt. Sigh. I'd suggest groupby but then how do I enter that in chatgpt?

Comment: What if the numbers in a day were 1/3/3/4/5? Or 1/2/6/7/8? Which ones woukd you flag?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use a  `groupby.cumcount`:

```
m = (df
   .groupby('TransactionDate').cumcount().add(1)
   .ne(df['TransactionNumber'])
)

out = df[m | m.groupby(df['TransactionDate']).shift(fill_value=False)]
```

Output:

```
  TransactionDate  TransactionNumber
7      08/13/2023                  3
8      08/13/2023                  3
```

Intermediates:

```
  TransactionDate  TransactionNumber  cumcount+1      m  m.shift(fill_value=False)  m|m.shift()
0      08/11/2023                  1           1  False                      False        False
1      08/11/2023                  2           2  False                      False        False
2      08/11/2023                  3           3  False                      False        False
3      08/12/2023                  1           1  False                      False        False
4      08/12/2023                  2           2  False                      False        False
5      08/12/2023                  3           3  False                      False        False
6      08/13/2023                  1           1  False                      False        False
7      08/13/2023                  3           2   True                      False         True
8      08/13/2023                  3           3  False                       True         True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"TransactionDate": "08/11/1990", "TransactionNumber": 1},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/11/1990", "TransactionNumber": 2},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/11/1990", "TransactionNumber": 3},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/12/1990", "TransactionNumber": 1},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/12/1990", "TransactionNumber": 2},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/12/1990", "TransactionNumber": 3},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/13/1990", "TransactionNumber": 1},
    {"TransactionDate": "08/13/1990", "TransactionNumber": 3},  # Missing number 2
    {"TransactionDate": "08/13/1990", "TransactionNumber": 3},  # Duplicate number
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert TransactionDate to datetime for accurate comparison
df['TransactionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TransactionDate'])


m1= ~df.groupby('TransactionDate')['TransactionNumber'].diff().eq(1)
df['m1'] =m1
m2 = ~df['TransactionNumber'].eq(1)
df['m2'] =m2

not_sequential =  (m1 & m2)
df['not_sequential'] = not_sequential
print(df.to_string())
"""
 TransactionDate  TransactionNumber     m1     m2     not_sequential
0      1990-08-11                  1   True  False           False
1      1990-08-11                  2  False   True           False
2      1990-08-11                  3  False   True           False
3      1990-08-12                  1   True  False           False
4      1990-08-12                  2  False   True           False
5      1990-08-12                  3  False   True           False
6      1990-08-13                  1   True  False           False
7      1990-08-13                  3   True   True            True
8      1990-08-13                  3   True   True            True
"""
res = df[not_sequential ]
print(res)
""" 
  TransactionDate  TransactionNumber    m1    m2  not_sequential
7      1990-08-13                  3  True  True            True
8      1990-08-13                  3  True  True            True
"""
```